# How to Change SSL Version for HTTPS Connections in JBoss EAP 6.1

Tags: ssl, https, jboss, jboss6.x

I have a simple HTTPS connector configured on my JBoss EAP 6.1 server for SSL connections to a bunch of RESTful web services I am working on.  I am not sure if JBoss EAP 6.1 comes with TLS 1.2 (or SSL 3.2, since I believe TLS is really just later versions of SSL), but I want to use that version of TLS or later.

What is the default SSL version of JBoss EAP 6.1 , if my standalone.xml file tags that handle this connector look like this? :

```
    <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
        <ssl name="https" key-alias="localhost" password="something" certificate-key-file="${jboss.server.config.dir}/localhost.jks"/>
    </connector>
```

There is no SSL version information given in the standalone.xml entry above, as you can see, so I've no idea.

I have read on the JBoss community web site that you can add something like  `sslProtocol="TLS"` in the  tag, and `protocol="TLSv2"` in the  tag, but is that really all there is to it?

i.e.

```
    <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS">
        <ssl name="https" key-alias="localhost" password="something" certificate-key-file="${jboss.server.config.dir}/localhost.jks" protocol="TLSv2" />
    </connector>
```

Will the above work, and if so, how can I tell?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: OK, thanks for the comment. I'll move it over to Stack Exchange shortly.

Answer (score 1):

According to redhat [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/Security_Guide/SSL_Connector_Reference1.html) for EAP 6.1

> protocol
>   The version of the SSL protocol to use. Supported values include SLv2, SSLv3, >TLSv1, SSLv2+SSLv3, and ALL. The default is ALL

Adding `sslProtocol="TLS"` and `protocol="TLSv2"` should work fine. Not to sound condescending, but the easiest way to see if it works is by testing it.

If this question *did* get moved to another SE site could you please provide the link?